# I am automatically getting the teams meeting whenever I try to make a meeting for folks but I dont want it a teams meeting

Tags: microsoft-outlook, teams

how do I stop the teams meeting from automatically being set up when trying to book a meeting with multiple people.  It needs to be an in person meeting not a teams meeting

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured in the options dialog:

Outlook->File->Options:

[image]

Uncheck checkbox `Add online meeting to all meetings`:

[image]

[support.microsoft.com: Make every meeting online](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/make-every-meeting-online-70f9bda0-fd29-498b-9757-6709cc1c73f0#:%7E:text=Select%20Calendar%2C%20and%20then%20choose,providers%20relevant%20for%20your%20account.)

> Whether you're working from home or meeting with people in other locations, Outlook can help you ensure every meeting is online. Simply enable the Add online meeting to all meetings option to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Markus Meyer. You need to disable the "Add online meeting to all meetings" option.

As a supplement, we can also click on "Don't Host Online" option manually to change your current meeting to conventional meeting from Teams meeting.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.